# Eliminate only values that SUM to 0 when meeting a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have a query which works perfectly, results are all correct, however a modification is needed to remove unused lines with a certain VOT and matching VONO.

Currently the query brings back a result set like this.

Sample 1

```
PART_NO TRANSACTION YEAR    QUANTITY    INV_COST    PARTSDESCRIPTION    COMPANY VONO            TEXT        YEAR_PERIOD_KEY ACCOUNT ACC         CODE_B  CODE_B_DESC CODE_C  CODE_C_DESC CODE_F  CODE_F_DESC REFERENCE_NUMBER    VOT     VOTD        AMOUNT  SUPPLIER_ID NAME        LINE_NO OBJECT_CLASS    FOCDESCRIPTION  ROW_NO   
10438   Issue       2015    1           12.39       coat                19      2015000314      Issue       201502          5635    Equipment   426     Floor       16      Operations  null    null        2869                MPL     11-FEB-15   12.39   null        null        null    null            null            2    
null    null        2015    null        null        null                19      2015000314      Automotive  201501          5513    Maintenance 426     Floor       16      Operations  80016   Mobile      MI074755            J       07-JAN-15   77.82   52254       Automotive  null    131100          Mobile          2    
null    Reg         2015    1           76.5        hose                19      2015000314      Register    201502          5490    consumable  426     Floor       16      Operations  E80009  Group       P42085              0       03-FEB-15   76.5    null        null        1       132300          Group           8    
null    null        2015    null        null        null                19      2015000314      Automotive  201501          5513    Maintenance 426     Floor       16      Operations  80016   Mobile      MI074755            J       07-JAN-15   -77.82  52254       Automotive  null    131100          Mobile          4    
null    Reg         2015    4           86.53       battery             19      2015000314      Register    201502          5430    Material    426     Floor       16      Operations  E80005  Running     P42092              0       03-FEB-15   346.12  null        null        1       142100          Runner          10
null    null        2015    null        null        null                19      2015000314      Automotive  201501          5513    Maintenance 426     Floor       16      Operations  80016   Mobile      MI074755            J       07-JAN-15   62.44   52254       Automotive  null    131100          Mobile          4
```

Now what i want to do is only when `VOT = J` and the VONO is same and the amounts cancel each other out i want them to not be shown (in this case the two values -77.82 and 77.82 cancel as they are VOT = J and they both are one the same VONO).

This would give a desired output like this:

```
PART_NO TRANSACTION YEAR    QUANTITY    INV_COST    PARTSDESCRIPTION    COMPANY VONO            TEXT        YEAR_PERIOD_KEY ACCOUNT ACC         CODE_B  CODE_B_DESC CODE_C  CODE_C_DESC CODE_F  CODE_F_DESC REFERENCE_NUMBER    VOT     VOTD        AMOUNT  SUPPLIER_ID NAME        LINE_NO OBJECT_CLASS    FOCDESCRIPTION  ROW_NO   
10438   Issue       2015    1           12.39       coat                19      2015000314      Issue       201502          5635    Equipment   426     Floor       16      Operations  null    null        2869                MPL     11-FEB-15   12.39   null        null        null    null            null            2    
null    Reg         2015    1           76.5        hose                19      2015000314      Register    201502          5490    consumable  426     Floor       16      Operations  E80009  Group       P42085              0       03-FEB-15   76.5    null        null        1       132300          Group           8    
null    Reg         2015    4           86.53       battery             19      2015000314      Register    201502          5430    Material    426     Floor       16      Operations  E80005  Running     P42092              0       03-FEB-15   346.12  null        null        1       142100          Runner          10
null    null        2015    null        null        null                19      2015000314      Automotive  201501          5513    Maintenance 426     Floor       16      Operations  80016   Mobile      MI074755            J       07-JAN-15   62.44   52254       Automotive  null    131100          Mobile          4
```

Currently the query is this and gives the first output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  pt.part_no, pt.TRANSACTION, g.year, pt.quantity, 
(g.amount/pt.quantity) as Inv_Cost, 
case when pc.description is null then p.description else pc.description end as partsdescription, 
g.company, g.vono, g.text, g.year_period_key, g.acc, g.code_b, g.code_b_desc, g.code_c,
g.code_c_desc, g.code_f, g.code_f_desc, g.reference_number, g.vot, g.votd, g.amount, 
s.supplier_id, s.NAME, p.line_no, foc.object_class, foc.description AS focdescription, 
g.row_no
FROM gen g
LEFT OUTER JOIN phist pt ON g.accid = pt.accid  
FULL OUTER JOIN partc pc ON pt.part_no = pc.part_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN pola p ON pt.order_no = p.order_no AND pt.rel = p.line_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sia s ON g.party_type_id = s.supplier_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cust c ON g.party_type_id = c.customer_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv d ON g.COMPANY = d.COMPANY AND g.vono = d.vonore AND g.vot = d.VOUCHER_TYPE_REF
LEFT OUTER JOIN III b ON d.company = b.company AND d.invid = b.invid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ob fo ON g.code_f = fo.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN obcl foc ON fo.object_class = foc.object_class
WHERE g.year = '2015' and g.company = '19'
AND (g.acc > '2999' OR g.acc IN ('1401','1450'))
AND g.code_b IN  ('426', '028', '124', '125') 
AND g.vot != 'MPL'
```

**Update (XQbert)**

Ok so here is a (BASIC)SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79611a/1/0

What is happening is that it is removing all VOT = J's rather than just the ones that total to 0 per VONO.

Sample Data:

```
PART_NO  TRANSACTION    YEAR        QUANTITY    INV_COST    PARTSDESCRIPTION    COMPANY VONO         TEXT       YEAR_PERIOD_KEY ACCOUNT  ACC            CODE_B  CODE_B_DESC CODE_C  CODE_C_DESC  CODE_F  CODE_F_DESC    REFERENCE_NUMBER    VOT  VOTD       AMOUNT   SUPPLIER_ID    NAME        LINE_NO  OBJECT_CLASS   FOCDESCRIPTION  ROW_NO 
10438    Issue          2015        1           12.39       coat                19      2015000314   Issue      201502          5635     Equipment      426     Floor       16      Operations   null    null           2869                MPL  11-FEB-15  12.39    null           null        null     null           null            2
null     null           2015        null        null        null                19      2015000314   Automotive 201501          5513     Maintenance    426     Floor       16      Operations   80016   Mobile         MI074755            J    07-JAN-15  77.82    52254          Automotive  null     131100         Mobile          2
null     Reg            2015        1           76.5        hose                19      2015000314   Register   201502          5490     consumable     426     Floor       16      Operations   E80009  Group          P42085              0    03-FEB-15  76.5     null           null        1        132300         Group           8
null     null           2015        null        null        null                19      2015000314   Automotive 201501          5513     Maintenance    426     Floor       16      Operations   80016   Mobile         MI074755            J    07-JAN-15  -77.82   52254          Automotive  null     131100         Mobile          4
null     Reg            2015        4           86.53       battery             19      2015000314   Register   201502          5430     Material       426     Floor       16      Operations   E80005  Running        P42092              0    03-FEB-15  346.12   null           null        1        142100         Runner          10
null     null           2015        null        null        null                19      2015000314   Automotive 201501          5513     Maintenance    426     Floor       16      Operations   80016   Mobile         MI074755            J    07-JAN-15  62.44    52254          Automotive  null     131100         Mobile          4
null     null           2015        null        null        null                19      2015000999   Bike       201507          5699     Parts          426     Floor       16      Operations   89999   fridge         MA864654            J    07-JUL-15  899.84   52254          Bike        null     65222          fridge          4
```

Output:

```
PART_NO  TRANSACTION    YEAR        QUANTITY    INV_COST    PARTSDESCRIPTION    COMPANY VONO         TEXT       YEAR_PERIOD_KEY ACCOUNT  ACC            CODE_B  CODE_B_DESC CODE_C  CODE_C_DESC  CODE_F  CODE_F_DESC    REFERENCE_NUMBER    VOT  VOTD       AMOUNT   SUPPLIER_ID    NAME        LINE_NO  OBJECT_CLASS   FOCDESCRIPTION  ROW_NO 
10438    Issue          2015        1           12.39       coat                19      2015000314   Issue      201502          5635     Equipment      426     Floor       16      Operations   null    null           2869                MPL  11-FEB-15  12.39    null           null        null     null           null            2
null     Reg            2015        1           76.5        hose                19      2015000314   Register   201502          5490     consumable     426     Floor       16      Operations   E80009  Group          P42085              0    03-FEB-15  76.5     null           null        1        132300         Group           8
null     Reg            2015        4           86.53       battery             19      2015000314   Register   201502          5430     Material       426     Floor       16      Operations   E80005  Running        P42092              0    03-FEB-15  346.12   null           null        1        142100         Runner          10
```

Expected Output:

```
PART_NO  TRANSACTION    YEAR        QUANTITY    INV_COST    PARTSDESCRIPTION    COMPANY VONO         TEXT       YEAR_PERIOD_KEY ACCOUNT  ACC            CODE_B  CODE_B_DESC CODE_C  CODE_C_DESC  CODE_F  CODE_F_DESC    REFERENCE_NUMBER    VOT  VOTD       AMOUNT   SUPPLIER_ID    NAME        LINE_NO  OBJECT_CLASS   FOCDESCRIPTION  ROW_NO 
10438    Issue          2015        1           12.39       coat                19      2015000314   Issue      201502          5635     Equipment      426     Floor       16      Operations   null    null           2869                MPL  11-FEB-15  12.39    null           null        null     null           null            2
null     Reg            2015        1           76.5        hose                19      2015000314   Register   201502          5490     consumable     426     Floor       16      Operations   E80009  Group          P42085              0    03-FEB-15  76.5     null           null        1        132300         Group           8
null     Reg            2015        4           86.53       battery             19      2015000314   Register   201502          5430     Material       426     Floor       16      Operations   E80005  Running        P42092              0    03-FEB-15  346.12   null           null        1        142100         Runner          10
null     null           2015        null        null        null                19      2015000314   Automotive 201501          5513     Maintenance    426     Floor       16      Operations   80016   Mobile         MI074755            J    07-JAN-15  62.44    52254          Automotive  null     131100         Mobile          4
null     null           2015        null        null        null                19      2015000999   Bike       201507          5699     Parts          426     Floor       16      Operations   89999   fridge         MA864654            J    07-JUL-15  899.84   52254          Bike        null     65222          fridge          4
```

Comment: What do you mean by "vono is same"? (Same as what?) Why don't you just add one more where filter on the conditions you mention?

Comment: So in the sample data i shown they are all the same VONO. so in a nutshell. if VOT = J and the VONO's match and they have zero-able values they can cancel out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9b2bc/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

I've added 3 rows to your data - two with +100 amount and one with -100 amount to show that this can handle unequal numbers of positive and negative rows. (and also changed the `AMOUNT` column to `NUMBER(10,2)`).

```
CREATE TABLE gen
    ("PART_NO" varchar2(5), "TRANSACTION" varchar2(5), "YEAR" int, "QUANTITY" varchar2(4), "INV_COST" varchar2(5), "PARTSDESCRIPTION" varchar2(7), "COMPANY" int, "VONO" int, "TEXT" varchar2(10), "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY" int, "ACCOUNT" int, "ACC" varchar2(11), "CODE_B" int, "CODE_B_DESC" varchar2(5), "CODE_C" int, "CODE_C_DESC" varchar2(10), "CODE_F" varchar2(6), "CODE_F_DESC" varchar2(7), "REFERENCE_NUMBER" varchar2(8), "VOT" varchar2(3), "VOTD" varchar2(30), "AMOUNT" NUMBER(10,2), "SUPPLIER_ID" varchar2(5), "NAME" varchar2(10), "LINE_NO" varchar2(4), "OBJECT_CLASS" varchar2(6), "FOCDESCRIPTION" varchar2(6), "ROW_NO" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES ('10438', 'Issue', 2015, '1', '12.39', 'coat', 19, 2015000314, 'Issue', 201502, 5635, 'Equipment', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', NULL, NULL, '2869', 'MPL', '11-Feb-2015 12:00:00 AM', 12.39, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2015, NULL, NULL, NULL, 19, 2015000314, 'Automotive', 201501, 5513, 'Maintenance', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', '80016', 'Mobile', 'MI074755', 'J', '07-Jan-2015 12:00:00 AM', 77.82, '52254', 'Automotive', NULL, '131100', 'Mobile', 2)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, 'Reg', 2015, '1', '76.5', 'hose', 19, 2015000314, 'Register', 201502, 5490, 'consumable', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', 'E80009', 'Group', 'P42085', '0', '03-Feb-2015 12:00:00 AM', 76.5, NULL, NULL, '1', '132300', 'Group', 8)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2015, NULL, NULL, NULL, 19, 2015000314, 'Automotive', 201501, 5513, 'Maintenance', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', '80016', 'Mobile', 'MI074755', 'J', '07-Jan-2015 12:00:00 AM', -77.82, '52254', 'Automotive', NULL, '131100', 'Mobile', 4)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, 'Reg', 2015, '4', '86.53', 'battery', 19, 2015000314, 'Register', 201502, 5430, 'Material', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', 'E80005', 'Running', 'P42092', '0', '03-Feb-2015 12:00:00 AM', 346.12, NULL, NULL, '1', '142100', 'Runner', 10)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2015, NULL, NULL, NULL, 19, 2015000314, 'Automotive', 201501, 5513, 'Maintenance', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', '80016', 'Mobile', 'MI074755', 'J', '07-Jan-2015 12:00:00 AM', 62.44, '52254', 'Automotive', NULL, '131100', 'Mobile', 4)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2015, NULL, NULL, NULL, 19, 2015000999, 'Bike', 201507, 5699, 'Parts', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', '89999', 'fridge', 'MA864654', 'J', '07-Jul-2015 12:00:00 AM', 899.84, '52254', 'Bike', NULL, '65222', 'fridge', 4)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2015, NULL, NULL, NULL, 19, 2015000314, 'Automotive', 201501, 5513, 'Maintenance', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', '80016', 'Mobile', 'MI074755', 'J', '07-Jan-2015 12:00:00 AM', 100.00, '52254', 'Automotive', NULL, '131100', 'Mobile', 4)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2015, NULL, NULL, NULL, 19, 2015000314, 'Automotive', 201501, 5513, 'Maintenance', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', '80016', 'Mobile', 'MI074755', 'J', '07-Jan-2015 12:00:00 AM', 100.00, '52254', 'Automotive', NULL, '131100', 'Mobile', 4)
    INTO gen ("PART_NO", "TRANSACTION", "YEAR", "QUANTITY", "INV_COST", "PARTSDESCRIPTION", "COMPANY", "VONO", "TEXT", "YEAR_PERIOD_KEY", "ACCOUNT", "ACC", "CODE_B", "CODE_B_DESC", "CODE_C", "CODE_C_DESC", "CODE_F", "CODE_F_DESC", "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "VOT", "VOTD", "AMOUNT", "SUPPLIER_ID", "NAME", "LINE_NO", "OBJECT_CLASS", "FOCDESCRIPTION", "ROW_NO")
         VALUES (NULL, NULL, 2015, NULL, NULL, NULL, 19, 2015000314, 'Automotive', 201501, 5513, 'Maintenance', 426, 'Floor', 16, 'Operations', '80016', 'Mobile', 'MI074755', 'J', '07-Jan-2015 12:00:00 AM', -100.00, '52254', 'Automotive', NULL, '131100', 'Mobile', 4)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
With UnindexedValues AS (
  SELECT * FROM gen
),
IndexedValues AS (
  SELECT v.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY VONO, VOT, AMOUNT ORDER BY VOTD ) AS AmtIdx
  FROM   UnindexedValues v
)
SELECT PART_NO, TRANSACTION, YEAR,
       QUANTITY, INV_COST, PARTSDESCRIPTION,
       COMPANY, VONO, TEXT,
       YEAR_PERIOD_KEY, ACCOUNT, ACC,
       CODE_B, CODE_B_DESC, CODE_C,
       CODE_C_DESC, CODE_F, CODE_F_DESC,
       REFERENCE_NUMBER, VOT, VOTD,
       AMOUNT, SUPPLIER_ID, NAME,
       LINE_NO, OBJECT_CLASS, FOCDESCRIPTION,
       ROW_NO
FROM   IndexedValues i
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 'X'
  FROM   IndexedValues x
  WHERE  i.VoNo   = x.VoNo
  AND    i.Vot    = x.Vot
  AND    i.Vot    = 'J'
  AND    i.Amount = -x.Amount
  AND    i.AmtIdx = x.AmtIdx
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9b2bc/1/0)**:

```
| PART_NO | TRANSACTION | YEAR | QUANTITY | INV_COST | PARTSDESCRIPTION | COMPANY |       VONO |       TEXT | YEAR_PERIOD_KEY | ACCOUNT |         ACC | CODE_B | CODE_B_DESC | CODE_C | CODE_C_DESC | CODE_F | CODE_F_DESC | REFERENCE_NUMBER | VOT |                    VOTD | AMOUNT | SUPPLIER_ID |       NAME | LINE_NO | OBJECT_CLASS | FOCDESCRIPTION | ROW_NO |
|---------|-------------|------|----------|----------|------------------|---------|------------|------------|-----------------|---------|-------------|--------|-------------|--------|-------------|--------|-------------|------------------|-----|-------------------------|--------|-------------|------------|---------|--------------|----------------|--------|
|  (null) |         Reg | 2015 |        1 |     76.5 |             hose |      19 | 2015000314 |   Register |          201502 |    5490 |  consumable |    426 |       Floor |     16 |  Operations | E80009 |       Group |           P42085 |   0 | 03-Feb-2015 12:00:00 AM |   76.5 |      (null) |     (null) |       1 |       132300 |          Group |      8 |
|   10438 |       Issue | 2015 |        1 |    12.39 |             coat |      19 | 2015000314 |      Issue |          201502 |    5635 |   Equipment |    426 |       Floor |     16 |  Operations | (null) |      (null) |             2869 | MPL | 11-Feb-2015 12:00:00 AM |  12.39 |      (null) |     (null) |  (null) |       (null) |         (null) |      2 |
|  (null) |      (null) | 2015 |   (null) |   (null) |           (null) |      19 | 2015000999 |       Bike |          201507 |    5699 |       Parts |    426 |       Floor |     16 |  Operations |  89999 |      fridge |         MA864654 |   J | 07-Jul-2015 12:00:00 AM | 899.84 |       52254 |       Bike |  (null) |        65222 |         fridge |      4 |
|  (null) |      (null) | 2015 |   (null) |   (null) |           (null) |      19 | 2015000314 | Automotive |          201501 |    5513 | Maintenance |    426 |       Floor |     16 |  Operations |  80016 |      Mobile |         MI074755 |   J | 07-Jan-2015 12:00:00 AM |  62.44 |       52254 | Automotive |  (null) |       131100 |         Mobile |      4 |
|  (null) |         Reg | 2015 |        4 |    86.53 |          battery |      19 | 2015000314 |   Register |          201502 |    5430 |    Material |    426 |       Floor |     16 |  Operations | E80005 |     Running |           P42092 |   0 | 03-Feb-2015 12:00:00 AM | 346.12 |      (null) |     (null) |       1 |       142100 |         Runner |     10 |
|  (null) |      (null) | 2015 |   (null) |   (null) |           (null) |      19 | 2015000314 | Automotive |          201501 |    5513 | Maintenance |    426 |       Floor |     16 |  Operations |  80016 |      Mobile |         MI074755 |   J | 07-Jan-2015 12:00:00 AM |    100 |       52254 | Automotive |  (null) |       131100 |         Mobile |      4 |
```

Comment: When i run this on its own it woks great, however when i run it  in my whole query (query 1 union all query 2) i get an error `ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns`

Comment: I've just been through all the columns and compared it to your expected output and the columns are all present (with no extra columns) and in the same order (which they should be since I did a copy/paste from the header line of your expected output to get the columns I needed to output).

Comment: would `AmtIdx` flag as an additional field?

Comment: Your expected output has an `ACCOUNT` column - your select query does not. I did my output based on your expected output - if that is not your expected output then please fix your expectations.

Comment: @Matt `AmtIdx` is not included in the output as I've explicitly named the columns to return and `AmtIdx` is not in that list.

Comment: got it working! my bad, i had added amtidx in the `SELECT PART_NO, TRANSACTION, YEAR.... FROM   IndexedValues i` part :)

Comment: This was the one that worked, it came down to 12 rows (out of 16000) but this one was correct

Answer (score 2):

Untested as sample data would be too complex...

This simply builds on what you've done.  There likely is a simple more elegant way.

What this does is generate a common table expression (CTE) and join join one CTE to another, on VoNo and ensuring both tables have a Vot of J and then negates one of the amounts from a table compairing to the other table if they match, it eliminates them.  **This would present a problem however if you have more than two amounts with the same VoNo  such as an additional amount of -75.  It too would be excluded... perhaps not as desired. But if data can't occur this way... no issue.**

Initial Response:

```
With CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT  pt.part_no, pt.TRANSACTION, g.year, pt.quantity, 
(g.amount/pt.quantity) as Inv_Cost, 
case when pc.description is null then p.description else pc.description end as partsdescription, 
g.company, g.vono, g.text, g.year_period_key, g.acc, g.code_b, g.code_b_desc, g.code_c,
g.code_c_desc, g.code_f, g.code_f_desc, g.reference_number, g.vot, g.votd, g.amount, 
s.supplier_id, s.NAME, p.line_no, foc.object_class, foc.description AS focdescription, 
g.row_no
FROM gen g
LEFT OUTER JOIN phist pt ON g.accid = pt.accid  
FULL OUTER JOIN partc pc ON pt.part_no = pc.part_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN pola p ON pt.order_no = p.order_no AND pt.rel = p.line_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sia s ON g.party_type_id = s.supplier_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cust c ON g.party_type_id = c.customer_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv d ON g.COMPANY = d.COMPANY AND g.vono = d.vonore AND g.vot = d.VOUCHER_TYPE_REF
LEFT OUTER JOIN III b ON d.company = b.company AND d.invid = b.invid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ob fo ON g.code_f = fo.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN obcl foc ON fo.object_class = foc.object_class
WHERE g.year = '2015' and g.company = '19'
AND (g.acc > '2999' OR g.acc IN ('1401','1450'))
AND g.code_b IN  ('426', '028', '124', '125') 
AND g.vot != 'MPL')

SELECT  * from CTE MINUS
SELECT A.* 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B
 on A.VoNo=B.VoNo
WHERE A.Amount+B.Amount = 0 
and A.Vot='J' and B.Vot='J'
```

With added union  (Putting union then cte union results will not work.  CTE has to be first and UNION has to be after the generated CTE but it could be before the 1st select or after the last.

```
With CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT  pt.part_no, pt.TRANSACTION, g.year, pt.quantity, 
(g.amount/pt.quantity) as Inv_Cost, 
case when pc.description is null then p.description else pc.description end as partsdescription, 
g.company, g.vono, g.text, g.year_period_key, g.acc, g.code_b, g.code_b_desc, g.code_c,
g.code_c_desc, g.code_f, g.code_f_desc, g.reference_number, g.vot, g.votd, g.amount, 
s.supplier_id, s.NAME, p.line_no, foc.object_class, foc.description AS focdescription, 
g.row_no
FROM gen g
LEFT OUTER JOIN phist pt ON g.accid = pt.accid  
FULL OUTER JOIN partc pc ON pt.part_no = pc.part_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN pola p ON pt.order_no = p.order_no AND pt.rel = p.line_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sia s ON g.party_type_id = s.supplier_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cust c ON g.party_type_id = c.customer_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv d ON g.COMPANY = d.COMPANY AND g.vono = d.vonore AND g.vot = d.VOUCHER_TYPE_REF
LEFT OUTER JOIN III b ON d.company = b.company AND d.invid = b.invid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ob fo ON g.code_f = fo.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN obcl foc ON fo.object_class = foc.object_class
WHERE g.year = '2015' and g.company = '19'
AND (g.acc > '2999' OR g.acc IN ('1401','1450'))
AND g.code_b IN  ('426', '028', '124', '125') 
AND g.vot != 'MPL')
--Could put your SELECT here
--UNION ALL
SELECT  * from CTE MINUS
SELECT A.* 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B
 on A.VoNo=B.VoNo
WHERE A.Amount+B.Amount = 0 
and A.Vot='J' and B.Vot='J'
--UNION ALL or here...
--YOUR UNION
```

Comment: Nearly there! This does the opposite and ONLY selects the two rows i dont want to see

Comment: I'm sure we could do this a different way, but since I know these results give us the opposite, using a `minus` operand should do the trick.  This is overhead I'm sure there's a better way, I just haven't put the brain power into it yet.  And given schedule, probably won't have the time.

Comment: Brilliant!! Preliminary testing works on the sample selection, i will try it now on all VONO's

Comment: I'm baffled why it generates the exact opposite... A.Amount*-1 <> B.Amount should exclude them... Guess my mind isn't working right...

Comment: found an issue... If the VOT = J but doesn't have a matching negative amount, its NOT showing it when it should be

Comment: hmmm... that implies I need a left join on the second select instead of an inner (updated).  but that may throw off other things...  Could a sample set of data be generated and placed in [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) so that I could play around with a few test cases?  going back and forth like this may take too long.

Comment: Not a problem,i will do it tonight and let you know the link. (left join didnt work)

Comment: Updated my question with a sql fiddle and some more sample data

Comment: @Matt I took a simpler approach http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79611a/7/0  I think this makes more sense, However it will still negate to zero twice if 3 records match on a.price - b.price = 0 and both records are J type.  Perhaps there's a key we should be joining on as well as it seems like this is processing returns that you don't want to include in results?

Comment: Excellent, this looks like it works however i have stumbled upon another issue, this query is half of the main query which are unioned. say the above is query 2, we have query 1 - union all - query 2. however i cant use WITH with a union :(  any ideas?

Comment: You can always eliminate the with by treating the queries as inline views.  I'll update my answer.  It's not as pretty to read but it works.

Comment: yeh, if you can re do it with inline? but also keep the oiginal answer as well

Comment: Wait.. what union doesn't work? it should... just place it after the CTE where the select begins.  But now you're making me want to revist the whole thing as this is UGLY to maintain.

Comment: Ah ok, so just put them the other way round?

Comment: Yep. should work  may want to check out @MT0 's response.  It appears much more elegant... but then i have the base selects in mine which we can't get away from.

Comment: Excellent work ! yours works perfect within the union now also. I will take a look at MT0's and they compare them both performance wise, currently i cant get MT0's to run but lets see! :)

Comment: This was very close, however, it came down to 12 rows (out of 16000) that were missing from this that should have been in it, and were in the other solutions results. still appreciate the answer and work put in though :)